# Converting Timecode to Frames from a text list with Applescript can this be done?

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I have two questions.

### First question

in a text file I have 600+  movie names and their timecode duration. I hope to convert the timecode duration to the equivalent frame count. Every movie time base is 25 frames per seconds. My text file looks like this:

```
MOVIE1.MOV [TAB] 00:02:12:05    
MOVIE2.MOV [TAB] 00:04:02:12    
MOVIE3.MOV [TAB] 00:00:32:19
```

How to convert this to a new file as follows?

```
MOVIE1.MOV [TAB] XXXX Frames
```

and so on?

### Second question

How to ask Quicktime Player 7 to open a movie file and place the playhead at a given frame?

Comment: I suggest editing this to just the first question and then start a new question for the second. This is the stack overflow way and you will be more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get you started. He's how you can take one of your timecodes and convert it to frames. Also if you have the movie open then it will move the playhead to the given time. You'll notice I don't actually need the frame to move the playhead, I only need the seconds. I hope this helps.

```
set timeCode to "00:02:12:05"

set wordsList to words of timeCode
set theSeconds to ((item 1 of wordsList) as number) * days + ((item 2 of wordsList) as number) * hours + ((item 3 of wordsList) as number) * minutes + (item 4 of wordsList) as number

set theFrame to 25 * theSeconds

tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    tell document 1
        set current time to theSeconds
    end tell
end tell
```